# Eloquent ORM | Laravel's hasMany (more than 1) relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Stackoverflow!

I'm usign Laravel. The question is about relations in Eloquent.

Item might have 1 or more than 1 types.

---

**Item.php:**

```
public function types() 
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Type');
}
```

---

**Type.php:**

```
public function items() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item');
}
```

---

**Item table:**

```
id
name
```

---

**Type table:**

```
id
name
```

---

**The question**

I have 4 types. Item №1 has 2 types, Item №2 has 1 type.
How should I store item types in database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define two `belongsToMany()`relationships. In the `Item` model:

```
public function types() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Type');
}
```

And in the `Type` model:

```
public function items() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item');
}
```

Also, create the `item_type` pivot table.

To work with this [many-to-many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) use the `attach()`, `detach()` and `sync()` methods.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for answer. I looked at [this laraveldaily tutorial](http://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/). Should I declare pivot table? `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item', 'items_types');`

Comment: @rikoart if you're following [Laravel naming conventions](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions) described in my repo, you can just use `item_type` pivot table. If you want to use another name for the table, you need to define it in both relationships.